# VBA Autofill formula with a fixed cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to autofill a formula to a range using vba.
What i am trying to do is to calculate a percentage contribution for each item.
Say i have 2 entries

> A1= 4
>
> A2= 6
>
> A3= sum of A1 and A2 =10

What i want is

> B1= A1/$A$3 = 40%
>
> B2= A2/$A$3 = 60%

but i am not quite sure how i could locate the last row of A and code it into the

> Range("B1").Formula= "=A1/?????"

any ideas would help!
Thanks

Comment: You cannot put a formula into A1 that references A1. That is called a circular reference.

Comment: sorry that was a typo, should be B1

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want a formula that devides the current cell by whatever the last filled cell in column A is? So if you have data in A1:A4 and the sum is in A5 you want =A1/$A$5 ?

Comment: yes, exactly right, but I want the code works for any rows with data.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this..

```
Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/INDEX(C[-1],MATCH(1E+99,C[-1]))"
```

You need to mention the range with circular references by specifying Row and column no from the active cell respectively like **`RC[-1]/R3C1`**

Comment: To *' locate the last row of A'* perhaps `=A1/INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,A:A ))`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So when i am working with VBA, reference style is quite important right?

Comment: Also I would like to know that how to make it dynamics, one thing to add here is Col A is dynamic in a sense that, it might be updated with 3 or more rows, say its generated by a pivot table. so i guess "=RC[-1]/R3C1" trick would work here...

Comment: I agree Jeeped thanks for the update and i have updated my answer accordingly :)

Comment: David please try the updated code it would work great for sure, since it will get the last filled row dynamically :)

Comment: sorry but allow me to add more conditions here, if the case is: Col A is the name, Col B is the sum, and i want Col C to be the percentage. And this table is generated using a pivot table making the entire pivot table not starting at A1, would the "match" method here useless? I am somehow thinking about using something like .End(xlDown).value

Comment: @David - Changing the conditions of a question sufficiently that valid answers are no longer valid is considered bad forum etiquette. Close this question off and start a new one if you have new requirements. See [Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions).

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to learn different coding approaches and styles for writing VBA. Actually the added condition is just a follow up question that expends the idea of the proposed answer.

Comment: Glad to know you got what you want, please accept it as answer so that if anyone looking for the same it will help them :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the last cell first, then sum it and add the formula to column B

```
  Sub Button1_Click()
        Dim LstRw As Long, rng As Range, Sm As Range

        LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LstRw)
        Set Sm = Cells(LstRw + 1, 1)

        Sm = Application.Sum(rng)
        rng.Offset(, 1) = "=a1/" & Sm.Address

    End Sub
```